# Google Calendar - Various usage limits and their handling

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing an app with Google Calendar API V3. I have doubts regarding the "**Usage limits**" provided by Google as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded).

Google has provided error response for 4 usage limits.

Out of which, app developer can set the values in API console to avoid 2 usage limits namely, **Daily Limit Exceeded** and **User Rate Limit Exceeded**.

Now on analysing this with my app, I have the following doubts.

1. How are the other two limits namely, **Rate Limit Exceeded** and **Calendar usage limits exceeded** set by Google? How can the developer handle there errors or avoid this in prior?
2. One can set user queries per 100 seconds per user in api console. However this is not reflected immediately. In a experimental testing, I have set 5 queries/100seconds/user. Initially I was able to make about 50 calls(varied each time) without any restriction and only after that, the api calls were restricted to 5 queries. Is this how the working is designed. Please clarify.
3. Sometimes, I am able to make calls even above the **Daily Quota Limit**. Is it possible always? I have set 1000 calls per day and was able to make api queries even above 1000 calls per day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gdata-api is no longer available (Calendar api v2) so I edited your post to remove the tag.